# Runs in Query Window but not from code what is the problem?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

The following SQL Command works in both my code and Access Query Window:

```sql
Insert Into [Check] (CheckNumber,CheckDate,Amount,WhoTo,Category) 
Values (1016,'5/10/2019 12:00:00 AM',123,'Steve',3)
```

But this SQL command only works from the Access Query Window, not from code

```sql
Insert Into [CheckMemo] (CheckNumber,Memo)
Values (1016,'Test')
```

I am using Access 2013 and the code is from C#
The connection string is

```c#
OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Checkbook.accdb;");
```

All other database functions that are in the program work great with the exception of the one described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memo` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) in MS Access.

As such, try enclosing this field name in square brackets, e.g.:

```sql
insert into [CheckMemo] (CheckNumber, [Memo]) values (1016, 'Test')
```